# Grunt custom targets

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Let's say I have 3 target modes for grunt: **quick**, **build** and **dist**

I also have a custom target `make-stuff`:

```
grunt.registerTask('make-stuff', [
            'someCSStask',
            'someUtility',
            'somePackage',
            'isolatedTask' // More on this below
        ]);
```

...that runs in all 3 of the above target modes *(quick, build, dist)* like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('quick', [
        'some-task1',
        'make-stuff'
    ]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'some-task1',
        'some-task2',
        'make-stuff'
    ]);

grunt.registerTask('dist', [
        'some-task3',
        'build' // make-stuff gets ran here since we reference 'build'
    ]);
```

I would like to run `make-stuff` normally in each target mode, except **quick**, where I want it to ignore **isolatedTask**

Answer (score 1):

If this is your setup, why not move 'isolatedTask' into build?

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'some-task1',
    'some-task2',
    'make-stuff',
    'isolatedTask'
]);
```

Otherwise, try something like this

```
grunt.registerTask(
   'isolatedTask',
   'Isolated tasks for make-stuff, skip if target mode is quick.',
   function() {
      var target = this.args[0];
      if (target === 'quick') { return; }

      // logic here
   }
);

grunt.registerTask(
   'quick', 
   function() {
      grunt.run.tasks([
          ...,
          'isolatedTask:' + this.nameArgs
      ]);
   }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @abeach3 where would I use `this.nameArgs !== 'quick'`

Comment: @bruh check the edits & let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is only working when I use `isolatedTask` as the condition. Using `quick`, the conditional statement is ignored when i run `grunt quick`. Is there something else I can use other than `this.nameArgs === 'quick'` or am I doing something wrong, because that only seems to work on *itself* - for example... `this.nameArgs === 'isolatedTask'` works fine... but it will obviously skip in all target modes.

Comment: Your totally right. I missed that when I was testing. This works - `grunt.registerTask('isolatedTask', function() { console.log(this.args[0]); }); grunt.registerTask('quick', function() { grunt.task.run(['isolatedTask:' + this.nameArgs]); });`. Definitely not as clean, maybe there's a better way...

Comment: Wrong use of jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/ecLnn0LL/](https://jsfiddle.net/ecLnn0LL/), but maybe this helps? This is my full gruntfile.js to model your issue.